# Evaluating the limit of a sequence: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\cos\pi n}{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I was trying to evaluate this limit of a sequence:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\frac{\cos\pi n}{n^2}.$$

This is not one of the indeterminate forms, is? Because looking at the behaviour of $\cos\pi n$ as $n$ gets sufficiently large, it won't approach a particular value or even approach either $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. The function values will just range from $-1$ to $1$. Am I right in this position? Thus, in my solution, I wrote, since $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos\pi n$ does not exist, so does $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\frac{\cos\pi n}{n^2}.$

I just want to be clarified if I give the correct reasons. Thank you.

Comment: Your reasoning was wrong. For example, $\lim_{n\to\infty} n$ does not exist, but $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{n}$ exists.
For this particular problem, you know $\left|\frac{\cos\pi n}{n^2}\right| \le \frac 1{n^2}$. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac 1{n^2} = 0$, the limit in question is also $0$.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint**

By the squeeze theorem

$$0\le\frac{|\cos(n\pi)|}{n^2}\le \frac1{n^2}$$
what we can conclude?

Comment: Oh, ok. Got it. Thanks @Sami

Comment: You're welcome.